# sshd: may ~/.ssh directory be symlinked

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

All the home directory dotfiles are symlinked into a repository, including the .ssh/.
ssh seems to work fine, but I'm unable to connect to my server, if it is using the same setup.

Tried changing the auth_keys config in sshd_config to

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  /data/progs/deps/homesick/repos/dotfiles/ssh/authorized_keys
```

but no-go:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I copy the whole dir to ~/.ssh, everything's back ok (this excluding all the permission issues et al.)

Does sshd allow symlinking the whole .ssh dir?

Comment: Are you keeping the **same** permissions in the new location for that file?

Comment: Yes, everything's the same.

Comment: And are you able to `cd /data/progs/deps/homesick/repos/dotfiles/ssh/` with the user you are doing `ssh` with?

Comment: Sure. I still feel like it's related to sshd's incompatibility when it comes to symlinks, but didn't find anything from the docs.

Comment: Could you try running `chmod 700 /data/progs/deps/homesick/repos/dotfiles/ssh/ && chown youruser:youruser /data/progs/deps/homesick/repos/dotfiles/ssh/` (replacing `youruser`, obviously) and try again?

Comment: Those were already the permissions of that dir. I use this little guy for fixing ssh-related perms issues:

    function sanitize_ssh() {
        local dir="$@"

        chmod -R u=rwX,g=,o= "$dir";
    }

Comment: If you add "-vvv" to your ssh command, it will print out (in great detail) everything that it is thinking and doing.  Usually, there's something in there that gives a clue as to what it is not happy about.

Comment: Yes, symlinks are not your issue.  I routinely symlink the .ssh folder.  I usually only get that message when my public key is not in the authorized_keys file