# can I symlink root's ~/.ssh to another user's? (for a local VM)

Tags: ssh, symbolic-link

(I am working on a VM on my local machine, so security isn't really important right now.  I wouldn't do this on an open machine).

I'm working on a complex build and spending a fair bit of time looking at config files and logfiles.

So I want to run `scp` outside of the vagrant folder, as root because the log files and config files have fairly restrictive permissions.

To do that I want to setup a broader ssh than just the built-in `vagrant ssh` which only works under the vagrant directory.

#### Step 1 copy a suitable key to the vm

do a `ssh-copy-id -i <somekey> vagrant@myvm`.

OK, at that point, provided I've picked the right key and it's loaded in the ssh-agent, I can now `ssh vagrant@myvm`.

#### Step 2, enable this for root too.

(if I do a `ssh-copy-id root`, I get asked for the password, no go), so instead I will copy the authorized keys.

ssh into vm as vagrant.

```
sudo -s
cd /root #root's home
#copy vagrants authorized keys.
cp -r /vagrant/.ssh .
```

**This works.**  i.e.  I can `ssh root@myvm`

What didn't work is I tried to replace the copy with `ln -s /home/vagrant/.ssh .ssh` while logged in as root.

replace `ln -s` with `cp -r` and everything works again.

Now, I do see a reason why this would be a good security - anyone with vagrant's user credentials could push in a new key onto vagrant and magically open it up for root as well, without performing any actions while logged in as root.

But, [sshd-may-ssh-directory-be-symlinked](https://superuser.com/questions/976186/sshd-may-ssh-directory-be-symlinked) says symlinked .ssh are OK.  There is actually no answer, just a comment.

So a) are symlink .ssh OK?  b) but not OK for root?

**env:  macos Sierra host, Ubuntu 16.04 guest, Vagrant 2.0.0**

Comment: You could always just hardlink the files within if they're on the same volume.

Comment: You can certainly use softlinks here so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@TooTea's comment under https://serverfault.com/a/951469/991587 was brilliant, may I rewrite it here?

For a key belonging to user1:

- `chmod 644` on the key allows user2 to use the key
- but user1 can't use his key anymore
- `chown nobody` removes this limitation and allows both user1 and user2 to use the key.

Warning, all other users can also use this key now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Too long for me to really know if that solves the problem - I don't use the same config anymore.  Upvoted and I'll accept if other people indicate that the solution worked for them.

Comment: That automated community bot commenting of unclear answer stuff is getting to be pretty spammy.  Why not let the *community* figure these things out rather than bot it?  Nothing all that unclear with the answer, just need to apply the steps to the particular config.  Works or not.